# how to convert function to str for Python?

Tags: python, serialization, python-3.6

Let's say I have a following lambda function.

```
fn = lambda x: print(x)
```

If I wanted to convert it to string

```
"lambda x: print(x)"
```

What can I do?
I was expecting `str(fn)` or `str(fn.__code__)` would do it but not really...it just prints out type, mem location, etc.

Also I've tried pickle.dumps and json as well, but i cannot get what I want.

How could I convert function to string that shows function definition?

--- I want to take function as an input and convert that into a string

Comment: You could keep it as a string and call eval when you want to run it.

Comment: @stark Thanks. But that's not what I want. I want to take function as an input, and convert that to a string

Comment: @KevinJJ if you are taking an input it would obviously be a string

Comment: @AmeyYadav Not necessarily ! I'm not reading input from a file or sth, it's more of a python client used in an interactive shell,

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's easy if you have installed dill. (`pip install dill`)

```
from dill.source import getsource
squared = lambda x:x**2
print(getsource(squared))
```

Comment: If you want to delete "squared = " then you can use str.replace or regular expressions.

Comment: Terrific! thanks. I wanted to vote it up, but it says my reputation is too low to do that :(

Comment: No problem ;) but you can check the answer as correct!

Comment: I like this answer but just to note, it displays the entire line(s) where the `lambda` is defined. For example, if defined in a function as is normal for lambdas, you'd get the wrapping function call (or at least part of it). Something like `foo(arg1, arg2, lambda x: print(x))`. `dill` uses information in the code object to read the source file and pull lines from there.

Comment: I am getting a number of errors: I installed dill, then when running the above it asks for "pyreadline" which I also installed, but then I still get the error: .... OSError: could not extract source code

Comment: @DISC-O, if the code is ran from the IDLE then it throws that error, but using it from a saved .py file seems to work fine.

Comment: I believe you can also use the built-in `inspect.getsource()` for this as long as you're not running in an interactive console

Answer (score 8):

Try it with `inspect`, which is part of Python3 standard lib:

```
import inspect

func = lambda e: e**2

print(inspect.getsource(func))
```

Returns a string:

func = lambda e: e**2

Comment: I tried your code and it raised OSError: could not get source code.

Comment: @MahmoudMagdy it only works if your code is being ran from a file. Look for an invocation of the function "getsourcelines" in your errors. If it's there, then check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57035364/inspect-getsourcelinesobject-shows-oserror-if-run-from-python-shell-but-gives