# inspect.getsourcelines(object) shows OSError if run from python shell but gives no error if run from a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, inspect

I tried this code-snippet inside a script named `test.py` :

```
from inspect import *

def f1(p,r):
    """Return f1 score from p,r"""
    return 2*p*r/(p+r)

print(getsourcelines(f1))
```

If I run this from terminal with `python3 test.py`, it outputs the following :

```
(['def f1(p,r):\n', '\t"""Return f1 score from p,r"""\n', '\treturn 2*p*r/(p+r)\n'], 3)
```

But, if I run the same whole script line by line inside python shell, it throws a `OSError`. This is what I tried in python shell along with the error :

```
>>> from inspect import *
>>> 
>>> def f1(p,r):
...     """Return f1 score from p,r"""
...     return 2*p*r/(p+r)
... 
>>> print(getsourcelines(f1))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 955, in getsourcelines
    lines, lnum = findsource(object)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 786, in findsource
    raise OSError('could not get source code')
OSError: could not get source code
>>>
```

Why does `inspect.getsourcelines(f1)` throws error inside python shell, but not when it is run form the file? Is there any other way to get the source lines of a function declared inside a python shell?

Comment: Yes, just as it says `could not get source code`. This function requires a file to read. When you run it inside the shell, there is no file.

Comment: As far as I know, no. It's reasonable. As there is no "location" concept in a shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour. `inspect` has only a limited support for builtin objects (not loaded from files).

It is explicit in other functions like `getsourcefile` where the doc says:

> This will fail with a TypeError if the object is a built-in module, class, or function.

Either if less explicit, the doc for `getsourcelines` says (emphasize mine):

> The source code is returned as a list of the lines corresponding to the object and the line number indicates where **in the original source file** the first line of code was found. An OSError is raised **if the source code cannot be retrieved**.

In the current versions, `getsourcelines` try to locate the function in the current source file. As it cannot get the current source file for the functions declared outside of a file, it raises an exception.

The underlying cause, is that when python is started in interactive mode, the main module is a builtin module and has no `__file__` attribute.

Comment: Is there a workaround? Please see my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60797338/get-ast-from-python-object-in-interpreter